# barplot ggplot with bars filled by values of another df

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi would to create a barplot like this [image]

but the bars should by filled by the values of this plot, leaving the rest in a color like gray or black:

[image]

To produce the barplots I used:

```
> table
      Var1 Freq
1  H3K27ac   72
2 H3K27me3   72
3 H3K36me3   72
4  H3K4me1   72
5  H3K4me2   66
6  H3K4me3   72
7   H3K9ac   66
8  H3K9me3   71
> table_filt
      Var1 Freq
1  H3K27ac   31
2 H3K27me3   72
3 H3K36me3    0
4  H3K4me1   71
5  H3K4me2   66
6  H3K4me3   72
7   H3K9ac   60
8  H3K9me3    1
```

and the  code is:

```
table%>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Freq, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours)

table_filt%>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Freq, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

The colour vector is:

> 

```
 colours
          H3K27ac          H3K27me3          H3K36me3           H3K4me1           H3K4me2           H3K4me3            H3K9ac           H3K9me3 
"mediumvioletred"         "#E69F00"         "#56B4E9"         "#009E73"         "#F0E442"         "#0072B2"      "firebrick4"      "aquamarine"
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: could you provide the colours vector?

Comment: so it would be like your second plot, with a gray bar in the third bar and its value comes from the first dataframe?

Comment: yes, a barplot with both informations. gray bars from first df filled with color by second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(table, aes(Var1, Freq)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray75") + 
  geom_col(data = table_filt, aes(fill = Var1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: uups already done, but my grey is different. :-)